# Reset selected range in rhandsontable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

How can I reset the selected cell range each time a new dataset is generated in the example below?

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton('gendata', 'Generate data'),
    hr(),
    verbatimTextOutput('verb'),
    hr(),
    rHandsontableOutput('table_original'),
    hr(),
    rHandsontableOutput('table_subset')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    mydata <- reactive({
      req(input$gendata)
      n_dim <- sample(2:8, 1)
      data.table( matrix(rnorm(n_dim**2), n_dim, n_dim) )
    })
    output$table_original <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(mydata())
      rhandsontable(data = mydata(), selectCallback = TRUE)
    })
    output$table_subset <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(input$table_original_select$select)
      selected_rows <- input$table_original_select$select$rAll
      selected_cols <- input$table_original_select$select$cAll
      DT <- hot_to_r(input$table_original)
      DT <- DT[selected_rows, ..selected_cols] # subset
      rhandsontable(DT)
    })
    output$verb <- renderPrint({
      str(input$table_original_select$select)
    })
  }
)
```

---

**Edit 1**
I think a solution might be to use javascript, but I am not familiar enought with this language to figure it out. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512812/how-to-reset-row-selection-in-rhandsontable-in-shiny-app) post.

---

**Edit 2**
I managed to avoid the error that was occuring when a new dataset was generated and the previous range was larger than the current dataset. I still hope that there can be a better solution.

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton('gendata', 'Generate data'),
    hr(),
    verbatimTextOutput('verb'),
    hr(),
    rHandsontableOutput('table_original'),
    hr(),
    rHandsontableOutput('table_subset')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    first_range_selection <<- TRUE
    
    mydata <- reactive({
      req(input$gendata)
      n_dim <- sample(2:8, 1)
      data.table( matrix(rnorm(n_dim**2), n_dim, n_dim) )
    })
    
    observeEvent(mydata(), {
      if (first_range_selection) {
        reset_range <<- FALSE
        first_range_selection <<- FALSE
      } else {
        reset_range <<- TRUE
      }
    })
    
    output$table_original <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(mydata())
      rhandsontable(data = mydata(), selectCallback = TRUE)
    })
    output$table_subset <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(input$table_original_select$select)
      if (reset_range) {
        reset_range <<- FALSE
        return()
      }
      selected_rows <- input$table_original_select$select$rAll
      selected_cols <- input$table_original_select$select$cAll
      DT <- hot_to_r(input$table_original)
      DT <- DT[selected_rows, ..selected_cols] # subset
      rhandsontable(DT)
    })
    output$verb <- renderPrint({
      str(input$table_original_select$select)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can program two `observeEvent`s:

- One that resets `output$table_subset` to NULL at `input$gendata`
- One that creates `output$table_subset` at `input$table_original_select`

This way it works fine on my side:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton('gendata', 'Generate data'),
    hr(),
    verbatimTextOutput('verb'),
    hr(),
    rHandsontableOutput('table_original'),
    hr(),
    rHandsontableOutput('table_subset')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    mydata <- reactive({
      req(input$gendata)
      n_dim <- sample(2:8, 1)
      data.table( matrix(rnorm(n_dim**2), n_dim, n_dim) )
    })
    
    output$table_original <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(mydata())
      rhandsontable(data = mydata(), selectCallback = TRUE)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$gendata, {
      output$table_subset <- NULL
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$table_original_select, {
      output$table_subset <- renderRHandsontable({
        req(input$table_original_select$select)
        selected_rows <- input$table_original_select$select$rAll
        selected_cols <- input$table_original_select$select$cAll
        DT <- hot_to_r(input$table_original)
        DT <- DT[selected_rows, ..selected_cols] # subset
        rhandsontable(DT)
      })
    })
    
    output$verb <- renderPrint({
      str(input$table_original_select$select)
    })
  }
)
```